# How to send images with Vue filepond via axios?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vuejs2, filepond

While trying to upload image with `vue-filepond`, I found the process confusing. The `files` prop is not saving the file after I upload an image.

Here is some code:

```html
<file-pond
    name="logo"
    allow-multiple="false"
    max-files="1"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    v-bind:files="images"
    :label-idle="label"
    v-on:processfile="onload"
    :server="server"
  />

<script>
export default{
  data() {
    return {
      images: [],
      server: {
        process: () => {
          console.log(this.myFiles);
        },
      },
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

I found the `images` array empty after uploading an image. I need to send the image to server via `axios`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `files` prop is intended to preload files. It doesn't get updated with files you actually drop onto the component.

To see which files are processed (uploaded), listen to the `processfile` event. To see which files were added (but not yet processed), listen to the `addfile` event:

```html
<template>
  <file-pond @processfile="onProcessFile" @addfile="onAddFile" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onProcessFile(error, file) {
      console.log('file processed', { error, file })
    },
    onAddFile(error, file) {
      console.log('file added', { error, file })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filepond-live-demo-forked-r3ji4?file=/src/components/FilePondDemo.vue)